# Coded UI Datasource MTM multiples values per parameter. How to not repeat entire script

Tags: c#, tfs, automation, coded-ui-tests

I have a Coded UI automated test pulling data from an MTM test case on a TFS.  There are multiple values for each parameter, and the script iterates though each row on the Test.  Unfortunately, the entire script is called.  There is a setup portion that should only be executed once.  How can I have the setup executed once, while the test method is called for every row?  Using a flag didn't work, the bool didn't retain a value between iterations.

Comment: How are you performing the setup/teardown? Normally this is done in a pair of methods attributed with [TestInitalize] [TestCLeanup] to setup and clean up once before the all the tests in the class to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Pete,

I have [TestInitalize] [TestCLeanup], but those run for every test.  [AssemblyInitialize] runs only once.  I had to sit down and read a chapter from a book. :(

MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx)

Turns out everyone in the office placed all iterations in one row separated by ';'s, then split the data.  I'll end up using the work-around for the sake of uniformity.